# Open LoginWindow before MainWindow?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I've tried using the answer found on this thread [Show login before MainWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909673/show-login-window-before-main-window), but changing the shut down parameters causes issues in my application.

What is classes as the best practice for this in WPF?

Comment: Does it close if you don't change it?

Answer (score 4):

I did not test this, but this should work.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    LoginFRM f = new LoginFRM();
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    f.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow();
    };

    if (f.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        mainWindow.show();
    }
}
```

Basically, the program would close if the window `Application.Current.MainWindow` is pointing closes. The first window instantiated is assigned to this property, so you should manually set this property to your own mainwindow, after the login window is being instantiated. Read more from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Edit

After some thoughts, it's probably better to do it this way:

```
// In App.xaml.cs:
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    LoginWindow loginWindow = new LoginWindow();
    loginWindow.ShowDialog();
}

// In LoginWindow.xaml.cs
public LoginWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Closed += LoginWindow_Closed;
}
protected void LoginWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.UserIsAuthenticated)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also check wether the user has authenticated. For Example if you create a custom principal check that is authorized and valid

Comment: Actually, it's possible to do it in the `Close` event of the login window as well. It's actually possible to instanstiate the main window there, and setup  `Application.Current.MainWindow` there, and even open the new main window there, after user passed authentication.

Comment: What class do I need for the "UserIsAuthenticated" method?

Comment: @Smithy It is a property, and login window should have its own logic to determine if the person logging in is to be given access or not.

Comment: Oh, Okay. I thought that was a method from the System.Security class.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `LoginWindow` is the main window of your application - that's the case if it is the first window opened in your application (which is automatically assigned as the application's main window). The application is by default configured to shut down if the main window is closed. So if you don't want to alter that configuration, your other option is to replace application's main window once you're ready to show the actual main window and before you close the login window. Here's an example method accomplishing this task:

```
void ShowMainWindow()
{
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow;
    mainWindow.Show();
    //I assume loginWindow is a reference to the LoginWindow being shown
    loginWindow.Close();
}
```